# How to count IMG tags within DIV using Xpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, java-8, webdriverwait

I want to count how many IMG tags there are under the surface div tag and echo the amount.

```
<div id="surface" style="width: 4567px; height: 4137px; left: -1850px; top: -1152px; cursor: default;">


<img src="https://media.memories.png" data-seat="L:106|EE:5" data-pl="1" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; width: 14px; height: 14px; left: 2221px; top: 1561px; display: block;">


<img src="https://media.memories.png" data-seat="L:106|EE:6" data-pl="1" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; width: 14px; height: 14px; left: 2237px; top: 1561px; display: block;">


<img src="https://media.memories.png" data-seat="L:106|EE:7" data-pl="1" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; width: 14px; height: 14px; left: 2253px; top: 1561px; display: block;">


<img src="https://media.memories.png" data-seat="L:106|EE:8" data-pl="1" style="position: absolute; cursor: pointer; width: 14px; height: 14px; left: 2269px; top: 1561px; display: block;">


</div>
```

Here is my non working attempt to get the count however its not returning the count to run my test in selenium IDE.

```
"//div[@surface='data-seat']/img"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Xpath result can be a NUMBER_TYPE. Try using the count() function in your xpath expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**
You can simply use the below xpath and then get the count.

xpath to Image - ***"//div[@id='surface']/img"***

```
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='surface']/img")).size());
```

**Option 2:**
If you want to make it more complex, use the js to run the query and return the count.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Long number_of_imgs = (Long) js.executeScript("return document.querySelectorAll(\"div[id='surface'] img\").length");
System.out.println(number_of_imgs);
```

I would prefer the option 1.

Comment: FYI, we are using CSS in Option 2 not xpath.

Comment: Thanks, i was able to use store xpath count on //div[@id='surface']/img and echo the result occurrences of IMG tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//div[@surface='data-seat']/count(img)
```

For your example html, it outputs `4`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath-1.0 expression

```
count(//div[@id='surface']/img)
```

It counts all `img` children of all `div` elements.

Answer (score 0):

To print the *count* of `<img>` tags within the `<div>` tag, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@id='surface']//img"))).size());
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div#surface img"))).size());
  ```